# Is "sonars" (plural) actually a word?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is "sonars" (plural) a word? I am not finding it in the online dictionaries, and I don't have access to my trusty "real" dictionary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ***Sonars***: https://www.google.it/search?q=%22sonars%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:2005,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&ei=gNbxVaLPEMjfUY_Xs_AK

Comment: Sonar is usually an [uncountable noun](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sonar). The question is whether you should say *sonar systems* or *sonars*. Note that *"sonar systems"* is unquestionably grammatical.

Comment: If it has a plural it must be a noun. (In English we do not usually pluralise adjectives). But is it a noun?

Comment: @WS2: *Sonar* is [definitely](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sonar) a noun. *Sonar* (SOund RAnging and Navigation) is a technique that uses sound waves to detect objects, just like *microscopy* is a technique that uses lenses to detect small objects, and *navigation* is a technique for figuring out which way to go.

Comment: ***Sonar*** : [count. noun] An apparatus used in sonar:
*we reduced the sensitivity of our scanning sonars* http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/it/definizione/inglese/sonar

Comment: @PeterShor  Interestingly the OED declares it to be a noun, but the majority of the examples it provides of its use show it being used as an adjective - *sonar cameras*, *sonar echoes*, *sonar waves*, *sonar devices* etc. Though there are admittedly some instances of a nounal use e.g. *the length of the foetus may be determined by sonar*. But I don't see how it could have a plural, any more than *radar* could.

Comment: this QA is utterly weird.  maybe it's a cultural thing.

Comment: you don't generally find **any** plurals in an English dictionary right?  you just assume you add an "s".

Comment: @WS2: those are adjectives in the same way that the first words in *"dog food"*, *"dinner party"*, *"chicken soup"*, and *"microscope slide"* are adjectives. In other words, they are technically noun adjuncts. You can't say *"this food is dog"*, *"my party is dinner"*, or *"your camera is sonar"*.

Comment: @WS2  You must be thinking of Soran. Sonar is SOund NAvigation and Ranging.

Comment: @deadrat The OED entry reads *1973   Brit. Med. Jrnl. 6 Oct. 28/1   The ‘in utero’ crown-rump length of the fetus may be determined by sonar in the first trimester of pregnancy.* Isn't *sonar* the same thing as *ultrasound*.

Comment: @WS2 It depends on how far away the fetus is and how fast it is moving.

Comment: @WS2 - they are utterly identical, except "ultrasound" uses higher frequencies.  quite simply,  **ultrasound is sonar with very high frequencies**.  "it's that simple."  Dead - what you said, is totally wrong. (You can tell that is the case from the upvote you got.)

Comment: WS2 note that "sonogram" is the usual word used for the image made from an ultrasound machine.  (which is to say, "...from an ultrasound sonar machine".)

Comment: note too that "ultrasound machines" (ie, for babies) are "imaging".  you can (and do) get sonars on submarines that are "imaging sonars".  conversely, you could imagine a (non-imaging) ultrasound sonar, for some purpose.  of course, "ultrasound" immediately makes you think of one of the (imaging) baby things; whereas "sonar" immediately makes you think of a fish-finder. (or, if you are so incredibly old you remember "WW2 movies", it may make you think, after thinking of the fish finder, of "that submarine beepy thing")

Comment: @JoeBlow - I now want to make an ultrasound imaging machine that makes a ping noise!

Comment: Quite.  Conversely I bet on submarines they make jokes about the output as if it is a baby imaging device!

Answer (score -1):

It seems extremely common and normal to use it as a noun.  Anyone who has ever been on any boat has heard someone say "look at the sonar".  No different from "look at the radio" or "look at the chair".

"Sonars" would just be the plural of "sonar".

For example,

[image]

This is an unusual use but, so what?  "televisions" is a somewhat unusual use ("at Sony we make forty different televisions") ... so what?

Note that "sonar" can also be used to describe the technology (as well as in other ways).  (Indeed, "television" can also be used to describe "the technology".)  You would be less likely to use the plural in that setting (although, you certainly *could*, same with television). It's a case of newsflash, in English words have many meanings.

If anyone reading doesn't know what a "sonar" is,

http://www.amazon.com/s/?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=sonar

(perhaps they have another name in other languages - I thought not).

Comment: I am still having trouble thinking that there is a thing called *a sonar*. Nor do I think there is *a television*, which simply means 'distance vision'.  There are *television receivers*, *television transmitters*, and *television personalities* - but *a television*? Similarly with *sonar*. These things are, at the most, mass nouns. But I'm still tending to think of them adjectivally.

Comment: Hi WS2.  I guess language moves on.  Very, very few people would even understand that "television" is anything other than the noun, ie, what you buy in a shop.  In BrE, a handful of people would.  In the UsaE, one or two people would know that.  In all the rest of the world that uses English, and any 2nd or 3rd world English, nobody would know it means anything other than the thing you buy in an electronics megastore.  You are, essentially, just pointing out that *"very old, very sophisticated people, know that it started as an adjective!"*  Heh!

Comment: You say radars to refer to multiple units, so why not sonars ?

Comment: @WS2 even Germans have several translations for Television...one of them is Fernsehgerat...or distance viewing apparatus.  But no one uses it.  Most people say "ich habe ein fernseher."  I have a television.

Comment: @JoeBlow  I would have thought 'sophistication', whatever that implies, would be something for which an intellectual mind (such as is attracted to this site) would normally strive. We use all kinds of language in a colloquial register, and I do not deny that I talk about 'shifting the television into the next room' - more likely I would say 'TV'. But there are also times, when I want to make myself clear, so I use correct English and say 'television receiver'. E.g when camping with some Boy Scouts  *We have got a signal, but no television receiver*

Comment: It's tough, I really want people to use decimate and apocryphal correctly.

Comment: @WS2 You wouldn't say "The television was broken, so I brought it to the shop"?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, as I pointed out to Joe Blow, I would say that informally. But if I was striving to be precise for some reason, and I was at the South Pole, I might say something like  *our television receiver is useless because we have no television signal*. We need to be clear about the limits of the informal expressions which we use.

Comment: I think "sophisticated" just means, essentially, educated, having "non-shallow" knowedlege of and ability to discourse about a topic. For example, my knowledge of, say, car breaking systems is only everyday, but some engineer from Porsche would have very sophisticated views on that; she could discourse on the topic in a sophisticated manner. Conversely of course, "sophist", as a dictionary says, brings to mind "...moral scepticism and specious reasoning." It's rather like, labelling someone an "intellectual" can be either a good thing, or a bad thing.

Answer (score -1):

So it turns out that "sonar" isn't a single thing.  There are many different types, which makes the plural a natural usage.  Books found via  the google:

> *Sonar**s** with High Noise and Clutter Rejection for Use with Adaptive
>   Robots
>  Multibeam Sonar**s**
>  Design Features of Advanced
>   Scanning Sonar**s** Based on Modulation Scanning*

Comment: Yes, as I explained in my answer, incredibly obscurely, you could use "sonars" more in the sense of the "plural of the technology concept".  of course, 99999 times out of 100000 when you use the everyday word "sonars", you are, obviously, just using the plural of a sonar.  for example, if you have three of [these](http://www.amazon.com/Lowrance-000-11448-001-Elite-3X-Fishfinder-Transducer/dp/B00MGAEU0S/) sitting around you may say "pass me those three sonars, buddy".

Comment: @JoeBlow I don't know, buddy.  I think you've had one too many as it is.